# UUID to be stored in file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, wmic

I am trying to get the `UUID` of the system and to store it in a file. using the command `wmic csproduct get UUID` I am getting the output file as (UUID some spaces then value) `i.e UUID                                                 4C4C4544-0031-5910-8048-B1C04F565331`.

But I need the value alone (`4C4C4544-0031-5910-8048-B1C04F565331`) in my output file.

Comment: [Basic string manipulation in windows batch files: dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php). Also: [en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

filter the line, you need:

```
wmic csproduct get uuid |find "-" >file.txt
```

EDIT in reply to your comment:

there is a more general way to get what you want:

```
for /f %%i in ('wmic cpu get ProcessorID /value^|find "="') do set id=%%i
```

Comment: Its Workin..Thanks..One more query, while gettin processor id, my output is (ProcessorId some spaces then value)ProcessorId             
BFEBFBFF000306A9. Can u help me to get the value alone (BFEBFBFF000306A9) in my output file.

Comment: @Gokulr added another way. Not as easy to read, but more flexible.

Comment: yeah..but how to print the variable(id) in output file..coz im gettin an empty output file..can u give me the complete code?

Comment: `echo %id% >>file.txt`?

Comment: but output is "ECHO is on."  complete code will be helpful.

Comment: that means, that your variable is empty. `echo(%id%` or `echo found: %id%` avoids "ECHO is on" message.