# Get the UUID of a computer using batch file and store it into a text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, uuid

I used these lines in a batch file:

```
@echo off
start  cmd /k "wmic csproduct get uuid"
```

to get the UUID of my computer.

I want to store the result into a text file. Is it possible and how?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UUID to be stored in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27397689/uuid-to-be-stored-in-file)

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
@echo off
start  cmd /k "wmic csproduct get uuid > C:\temp\yourfile.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "skip=1delims=" %%a in ('wmic csproduct get uuid') do set "uuid=%%a"&goto gotuuid
:gotuuid
echo "%uuid%"
```

The `skip=1` skips the first `wmic` line-output (which contains the literal "UUID"); the variables is set to the contents of the next line and the `goto` ensures that just one line is processed.

Answer (score 0):

The output is usually padded with trailing spaces up to a defined length.

Try this:

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "Skip=1 Delims=" %%A In ('WMIC CSProduct Get UUID'
) Do For %%B In (%%A) Do Call :Sub %%A
Exit/B

:Sub
(Echo %*)>MyUUID.txt
```